# Error: The URL does not use a recognized protocol

Tags: http, hp-uft

We are launching a HP UFT test about the urls contained in a web application. We are trying to verify if the links are broken or not. We have a list of links stored in a excel file and we run a for loop to pass each urls to the function TestPageLinks. The following codes is out current function, but we are getting error **"The URL does not use a recognized protocol."** Anyone has ideas what may go wrong?

P.S We tried some urls hosted on public protocols like google.com and youtube.com and they all worked. But we have to make it work on the urls in our own web app.

Test Function:
[image: TestPageLinks function]

Reporting:
[image: Reporting, where we call our function]

Comment: I think the most important detail of this question is missing, can you give an example of some of the links that fail?

Answer (score 2):

The protocol of a link is the part before the `://`.

- **http**://example.com
- **https**://google.com
- **ftp**://somesite.com

Do your links include this part?

Comment: not sure why this was down voted. In the absence of more specificity it is a perfectly legit answer, and worked for me.